# Convert datetime to Y-m-d H:i:s format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a datetime field which saves the date in numerical format:

`2013-11-23 21:21:31`

I want to format this value into Y-m-d H:i:s so that instead of a list of numbers it reads as:

`23rd November 2013`

with or without the time, doesn't really matter too much.

Is this possible using `date()` or is that just for submitting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date string to a timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/date) and feed it to [`date()`](http://php.net/date):

```
echo date('jS F Y', strtotime($dateStringFromDB));
```

For other available formatting options, refer to the documentation for [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

Comment: This won't work because I'm not actually using `2013-11-23 21:21:31`, I'm getting dates using a variable.

Comment: @SethForza: Sure, it would. You can substitute the string with a variable. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I set the variable.